# Mysql not restarting

Tags: mysql

In my linux server when perform mysql restart by using the following command

```
service mysql restart 
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: 
Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

How to fix this issue

Comment: Are you in a chroot?

Comment: No i checked /etc/mysql/my.cnf there its commented out

Comment: What is the output of `stat -c %i /`?

Comment: i am getting this value 19941688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are in a [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot). Take a look at [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot) for more details.

Upstart acts as a service supervisor. The processes within a chroot are unable to communicate with the Upstart running outside of the chroot. A workaround for this is configure chroots with `/sbin/initctl` pointing to `/bin/true`:

```
# dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
# ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

[Read more...](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/430224)

Comment: it worked but now i cant login by using mysql username and password through phpmyadmin but i cam login to the mysql server by using the username and password from command line plz help

Comment: How did you configure phpMyAdmin? What options do you use from the command line?

Comment: mysql -u username -p then i gave the password i was able to do login? i am getting mysql> prompt but when i try  http://servrname/phpmyadmin and when i gave username and password given its showing #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: What does `config.inc.php` look like? Did you take a look at the Apache's error log?

Comment: @qunata changed the entry in config.inc.php 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; to
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
and restarted apache that has done the trick thanks for your help and also for your valuable time

Comment: Keep in mind that: localhost ~ connect via Unix socket, 127.0.0.1 ~ connect via TCP/IP.